# SQL Server CE 4.0 membership db - unable to connect through the Web Site Administration tool

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Using Visual Studio 2012, I created a new ASP.NET MVC 4 web project,
using NuGet, I installed the "Microsoft SQL Server CE 4.0 Universal providers for SQL compact Edition".

After that:

I found the aspnet.sdf SQL Server CE 4.0 database sitting in my App_Data folder

I registered successfuly on my MVC site giving a user name and a password, I can login.

When I display the \App_Data\aspnet.sdf users table, I find no records.

The problem here, is that when I click on the VS Menu: **PROJECT** -> **Asp.net configuration** I get on my browser the "**Web site Administration Tools**" with  the registered user, I assume here that the db used here is not the same created in my web site.
When I want to change the data store in the "Security installation wizard" I get the next message:
"*Your application is currently configured to use:
**Advanced Settings suppliers**
To change the data store for your application, close the wizard, and then click Security Configuration tab provider. You can use this tab to configure how to store the data management websites.*"

When I go to the Security Configuration tab provider, and click on test link beside the unique provider found: AspNetSqlProvider, I get the following message:

"*Cannot establish a connection to the database.
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the command line utility to create and configure aspnet_regsql the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.*"

Please advise what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the MVC4 template using simple membership the "Web site Administration Tools" will not work with simple membership. It is not supported in this case

Answer (score 0):

I bet it is because the default aspnetsqlprovider is using this connection string "data source =.\sqlexpress" in the machine.config.
However, if you use MS SQL CE, your connection should be "Data Source=aspnet.sdf" (you may check the right connection string from the connectionstrings.com)